# not able to read attribute in foreach?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the style property of some divs, but I am not able to do so, when I console log the style property I am getting undefined.

```
var divs = $('#addDescription').parent().children('div');
        divs.each(function (i)
        {
            //console.log("wid", $(i).css("width"))
           console.log( $(i).attr("style"))
            $(i).removeAttr("style");

        });
```

why I am not able to read the style property using foreach?

Comment: You are not using correct parameter of callback, `each(function (index, element)` then use `element` i.e. `$(element).attr("style")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` in place of  `var i`. The `i` is the Index, the nth item of the selection (e.g. 0,1,2,3, etc).
jQuery gives you a `this`, which refers to one element per itteration.

```
var divs = $('#addDescription').parent().children('div');
divs.each(function (i){
    //console.log("wid", $(i).css("width"))
    console.log( $(this).attr("style"))
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
});
```

Comment: Clean up the code, and expended the answer a bit for you :) Also try to explain as much as (reasonably) possible.

Comment: Ahh.. OK @Martijn. Thanks